# Text Summarization with Python using sumy in .net

Tags: python, c#, .net

I have the following simple code,

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string pythonDll = @"C:\Users\garry.walters\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDll);
            PythonEngine.Initialize();

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic sumy = Py.Import("sumy");

                dynamic lsaSummarizer = Py.Import("sumy.summarizers.lsa.LsaSummarizer");

                string inputText = "This is the input text. Add more texts";

                dynamic summarizer = lsaSummarizer();

                dynamic parser = Py.Call(sumy.parsers.plaintext.PlaintextParser, inputText);

                dynamic summary = Py.Call(summarizer, parser.document, 5); 
                Console.WriteLine("Summary:");
                Console.WriteLine(summary);
            }
    }
}
```

It returns an error `Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'No module named 'sumy.summarizers.lsa.LsaSummarizer'; 'sumy.summarizers.lsa' is not a package'`
when it hits the line `dynamic lsaSummarizer = Py.Import("sumy.summarizers.lsa.LsaSummarizer");`

I have installed sumy, am I missing something else?

Comment: Maybe because `sumy.summarizers.lsa` is just a file and not the package? What if you try something like `dynamic lsa = Py.Import("sumy.summarizers.lsa");` and then `lsa. LsaSummarizer()`?